# Dynamically assigning an object/dict method that overwrites itself with a function result on first access

Tags: python, caching, optimization, memoization

I figured this would be a fun Sunday morning problem to work out.  It's been 3 hours and I'm nowhere close...

Background:

I'm using `dogpile` to cache read-only data from `SqlAlchemy`.

I convert a row of data into a custom subclass of `dict` called `ObjectifiedDict` .  This just lets me treat the dict with object notation, so I can use the same templates and helpers for these read-only dicts as I do with the active SqlAlchemy objects.  ( I also like storing cached data as dicts , so I can use the same cached values for other apps or languages )

Everything is working perfectly.

I've been exploring ways to make caching a bit better, and rembered Pyramid's `@reify` decorator ( http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/decorator.html ).  @reify lets an object method overwrite itself with the return value of the funciton, this way the underlying function is only called once.  This idea is very attractive to me for caching purposes.

[ As mentioned in comments, memoization is a more proper term ]

Problem:

I'm at a loss though on how to best approach something like this.  Trying to dynamically set the object properties to redefine themselves is way harder than I thought it would be.  `@reify` is so simple and works so well because it's on a predefined class.

The best of what I've come up with so far is this...

```
class ReifiedObjectFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, object , object_attribute, function , *args , **kwargs ):
        self.object = object
        self.object_attribute = object_attribute
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        try:
            self.__doc__ = function.__doc__
        except: # pragma: no cover
            pass
    def __repr__(self):
        val = self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
        setattr( self.object , self.object_attribute , val )
        return val


class ObjectifiedDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        if attr in self:
            return self[attr]
        return self.__getattribute__(attr)
    def lazyload( self, attr , function , *args , **kwargs ):
        self[attr] = ReifiedObjectFunction(self,attr,function,*args,**kwargs)


def lazyloaded_function(*args,**kwargs):
    print 'compute lazyloaded_function %s,%s' % ( args , kwargs )
    return "%s" % args


sample = ObjectifiedDict({'a':'a','b':'bb','c':'ccc'})
print "get a"
print "     %s" % sample.a
print "get b"
print "     %s" % sample.b
print "set d"
sample.lazyload( 'd' , lazyloaded_function , "dddd" )
print "d is set"
print "sample : %s" % sample
print "get d"
print "     %s" % sample.d
print "get d again"
print "     %s" % sample.d
print "sample : %s" % sample
```

This has a few obvious and huge caveats though.  It only works on string context ( because I'm overloading **repr** ) and I can only return string values.

Anyone have clues on how I should proceed ?

**Update:**

I've come up with this working example of what i want to do.  does anyone see any issues with this approach :

```
class LazyloadedFunction(object):

    def __init__(self, object , object_attribute, function , *args , **kwargs ):
        self.object = object
        self.object_attribute = object_attribute
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        try:
            self.__doc__ = function.__doc__
        except: # pragma: no cover
            pass

    def execute(self):
        val = self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
        return val


class ObjectifiedDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self,attr):
        if attr in self:
            item = dict.__getitem__(self,attr)
            if isinstance( item , LazyloadedFunction ):
                item = item.execute()
                dict.__setitem__( self , attr , item )
            return item

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        if attr in self:
            if isinstance( self[attr] , LazyloadedFunction ):
                self[attr] = self[attr].execute()
            return self[attr]
        return self.__getattribute__(attr)

    def __getattribute__(self,attr):
        return dict.__getattribute__(self,attr)

    def lazyload( self, attr , function , *args , **kwargs ):
        self[attr] = LazyloadedFunction(self,attr,function,*args,**kwargs)


def lazyloaded_function(*args,**kwargs):
    print 'compute lazyloaded_function %s,%s' % ( args , kwargs )
    return [1,2,3]


sample_a = ObjectifiedDict({'a':'a','b':'bb','c':'ccc'})
sample_a.lazyload( 'd' , lazyloaded_function , "dddd" )

sample_b = ObjectifiedDict({'a':'a','b':'bb','c':'ccc'})
sample_b.lazyload( 'd' , lazyloaded_function , "dddd" )

print "sample_a"
print sample_a
print "sample_a.d = %s" % sample_a.d
print sample_a

print "====="

print "sample_b"
print sample_b
print "sample_b['d'] = %s" % sample_b['d']
print sample_b
```

Comment: isn't that just memoization?

Comment: memoization would be a better term.  i was using reification from the pyramid method.  i'll adjust the question & tag.